# Extending class not working unless you copy all methods

Tags: class, inheritance

In my module I want to overwrite the method
`public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)` in 
`Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract`.

If I copy only that method in my class:

```
class Company_Module_SalesRule_Model_Quote_Discount extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract
{
  public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
   {
       parent::collect($address);
       $quote = $address->getQuote();
       $store = Mage::app()->getStore($quote->getStoreId());
       $this->_calculator->reset($address);
```

I get:

```
Call to a member function reset() on a non-object
```

If I copy all other methods and variables from that file it will work.

I wonder why is that when you're extending a class.

In config.xml:

```
<models>
            <Module>
                <class>Company_Module_Model</class>
            </Module>
            <salesrule>
                <rewrite>
                    <quote_discount>Company_Module_SalesRule_Model_Quote_Discount</quote_discount>
                </rewrite>
            </salesrule>
        </models>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to extend the class that you rewrite to inherit its methods, not its parent as you did.

```
class Company_Module_SalesRule_Model_Quote_Discount
    extends Mage_SalesRule_Model_Quote_Discount
```

Comment: I don't have the code available now but I reckon the fact that he wants to extend an abstract class can also be an issue

Comment: I then get the error `"The address total model should be extended from Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract  in pp/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Collector.php`

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism He wants to rewrite a concrete class. That the rewritten method is defined in an abstract class does not make a difference.

Comment: @fschmengler got mislead by the start of the post ;)

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga the class `Mage_SelesRule_Model_Quote_Discount` **does** extend `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract` ([source](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Quote/Discount.php#L34)). Inheritance is transitive, so if you inherit from your father, you also inherit from your father's father. If you get this error message, you did a mistake somewhere else, maybe in `app/code/local/Mage`

Comment: it was an issue in my config.xml

Comment: one quick question, if that method that I am overwriting includes `parent::collect($address);` than is it an issue? I find that if In replace it with `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract::collect($address);` than it is working. `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract` being the father's father

Comment: Yes, you found the correct way to call the grandparent's method